# siunitx's S column doesn't align properly

Tags: tables, siunitx, columns

I've following table and have obviously a problem...
What's wrong with my code?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c
        |S[table-number-alignment = right]
        |S[table-number-alignment = right]
        |S[table-number-alignment = right]
        |S[table-number-alignment = right]
        |S[table-number-alignment = right]
        |}
    \hline
       & {Jahr 1} & {Jahr 2} & {Jahr 3} & {Jahr 5} & {Jahr 5} \\
    \hline
    V1 & 5000     & 5500     & 6050     & 6655     & 7321     \\
    \hline
    V2 & 3,5      & 4        & 4,5      & 5        & 5,5      \\
    \hline
    V3 & 17500    & 22000    & 27225    & 33275    & 40266    \\
    \hline
    V4 & 0,6      & 0,64     & 0,68     & 0,72     & 0,76     \\
    \hline
    V5 & 3000     & 3520     & 4114     & 4792     & 5564     \\
    \hline
    V6 & 2000     & 2000     & 2500     & 2500     & 2500     \\
    \hline
    V7 & 15000    & 15000    & 15000    & 15000    & 15000    \\
    \hline
    V8 & 6250     & 6250     & 6250     & 6250     & 6250     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default values are not sufficient. Since the rows are processed row by row, package `siunitx` does not know beforehand, how long the numbers are. Therefore, the width of the numbers can be specified with option `table-format`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c
        |S[table-number-alignment = right, table-format=5.1]
        |S[table-number-alignment = right, table-format=5.2]
        |S[table-number-alignment = right, table-format=5.2]
        |S[table-number-alignment = right, table-format=5.2]
        |S[table-number-alignment = right, table-format=5.2]
        |}
    \hline
    & {Jahr 1} & {Jahr 2} & {Jahr 3} & {Jahr 5} & {Jahr 5} \\
    \hline
    V1 & 5000 & 5500 & 6050 & 6655 & 7321 \\
    \hline
    V2 & 3,5 & 4 & 4,5 & 5 & 5,5 \\
    \hline
    V3 & 17500 & 22000 & 27225 & 33275 & 40266 \\
    \hline
    V4 & 0,6 & 0,64 & 0,68 & 0,72 & 0,76 \\
    \hline
    V5 & 3000 & 3520 & 4114 & 4792 & 5564 \\
    \hline
    V6 & 2000 & 2000 & 2500 & 2500 & 2500 \\
    \hline
    V7 & 15000 & 15000 & 15000 & 15000 & 15000 \\
    \hline
    V8 & 6250 & 6250 & 6250 & 6250 & 6250 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Also, there are lots of lines. Nicer tables can be done without vertical lines and less horizontal lines, see package `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headings=small]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c
        S[table-format=5.1]
        S[table-format=5.2]
        S[table-format=5.2]
        S[table-format=5.2]
        S[table-format=5.2]
        }
    \toprule
    & {Jahr 1} & {Jahr 2} & {Jahr 3} & {Jahr 5} & {Jahr 5} \\
    \midrule
    V1 & 5000 & 5500 & 6050 & 6655 & 7321 \\
    V2 & 3,5 & 4 & 4,5 & 5 & 5,5 \\
    V3 & 17500 & 22000 & 27225 & 33275 & 40266 \\
    V4 & 0,6 & 0,64 & 0,68 & 0,72 & 0,76 \\
    V5 & 3000 & 3520 & 4114 & 4792 & 5564 \\
    V6 & 2000 & 2000 & 2500 & 2500 & 2500 \\
    V7 & 15000 & 15000 & 15000 & 15000 & 15000 \\
    V8 & 6250 & 6250 & 6250 & 6250 & 6250 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I thought, the S column could also auto-assign width like the c column, so that was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You may shorten the code, and add some vertical padding to cells:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, headings=small]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-number-alignment = right, table-format =5.2}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c |S[table-format=5.1] |*{4}{S|}}
    \hline
    & {Jahr 1} & {Jahr 2} & {Jahr 3} & {Jahr 5} & {Jahr 5} \\
    \hline
    V1 & 5000 & 5500 & 6050 & 6655 & 7321 \\
    \hline
    V2 & 3,5 & 4 & 4,5 & 5 & 5,5 \\
    \hline
    V3 & 17500 & 22000 & 27225 & 33275 & 40266 \\
    \hline
    V4 & 0,6 & 0,64 & 0,68 & 0,72 & 0,76 \\
    \hline
    V5 & 3000 & 3520 & 4114 & 4792 & 5564 \\
    \hline
    V6 & 2000 & 2000 & 2500 & 2500 & 2500 \\
    \hline
    V7 & 15000 & 15000 & 15000 & 15000 & 15000 \\
    \hline
    V8 & 6250 & 6250 & 6250 & 6250 & 6250 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]